# How to write dynamic query with % string compare?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic

I am writing a dynamic query in a pl/sql procedure, in which I want to retrieve records based on a string comparison operation. I have my strings stored in a variable and I want to use it in a query.

```
x:='A';
select * from table_name where category like 'A%SITE';
```

I want to somehow convert the above into a dynamic query and substitute variable x for A in 'A%SITE' and I am not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string concatenation:

```sql
DECLARE
  x   VARCHAR2(20);
  cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  x := 'A';

  OPEN cur FOR
    select *
    from   table_name
    where  category like x || '%SITE';

  -- Do something with the cursor.
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=738c07b69bc8b599b91aa4734d520d7e)*

---

Regarding you comment:

> ```sql
> EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select * from table_name where category like x || '%SITE''
> ```

You need to escape the quotes by doubling them up and you probably also want to use a bind variable (to prevent SQL injection attacks):

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  'select * from table_name where category like :1 || ''%SITE'''
  USING x;
```

However, there is nothing in that query that requires dynamic SQL and you can do exactly the same without dynamic SQL if you either use a cursor (as per my example above) or use `SELECT ... [BULK COLLECT] INTO`.

Comment: yes was trying that but since this will have to be a dynamic query because x is unknown at compile time I don't know how to escape the quote

Comment: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select *
    from   table_name
    where  category like x || '%SITE''

Comment: Ok will look to do this without dynamic query thank you so much for your help!